# Enabling QGIS Official Plugin Repository in the 3.4.1 Version?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I am using QGIS version 3.4.1.
Recently, I cannot install new plugins. I have looked in the plugin setting. It seems that the link is blocked. The address is "https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml" and it is directed to the "[QGIS Python Plugins](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml)" website.

[image]

In the log Messages I have this warning "WARNING: Failed to load C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/plugins/grassplugin7.dll (Reason: Cannot load library C".

I have a proxy from my university, disabling the automatic configuration script did not solve the problem.

[image]

Also, re-installing QGIS did not help.
What else should I look into in order to enable the plugin link?

Comment: Can you access the adress with a browser or with ping?

Comment: I added the data regarding the address to the question.

Comment: I have the same problem. Browser access is free. Proxy is not used. Before the upgrade to version 3.4, everything worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151841)

Answer (score 1):

Try with http instead of https: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml

I had the same problem and this worked.

You can check your proxy setting via "help - check QGIS version" independently of the plugins access.